# Asynchronous methods in RubyCocoa

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, user-interface, asynchronous, ruby-cocoa

I understand that it isn't possible/sensible to use threads in RubyCocoa. However it is possible to use asynchronous Cocoa methods to avoid blocking user interface events.

I've successfully used a method on `NSURLConnection` to send an HTTP request and receive the response without blocking the user interface. But I'm wondering what other asynchronous Cocoa methods like this are available?

Also is it possible/sensible within a RubyCocoa application to use Ruby to spawn separate processes (as opposed to threads)? I suppose one issue would be how to wait for the process to complete, but perhaps this could be done by polling via NSTimer events?

Answer (score -1):

Check this client, it's written in ruby and works pretty well.
[httpclient](http://dev.ctor.org/http-access2/wiki/WikiStart#a20090611:httpclient/2.1.5.1)

Comment: I've moved away from using a Ruby HTTP client specifically to avoid blocking user interface events. My question is not about how to make HTTP requests in RubyCocoa, but how to perform long-running tasks without blocking the user interface.